# Element compiled and appended from inside directive is added, but ng-click function doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Basically what I'm trying to do is to override the right click for certain elements, and instead display a short menu that lets you pick 'setClear' or 'unsetClear'. If I add the custom context menu to the body of the HTML directly then it works fine, but I don't want to have to add one for every instance of the directive, I'd prefer to have the directive create and append the menu itself since the ng-click function will pass a variable that will be different in each case.

At the moment, the right click is being overridden, and when I right click on the element I get the menu. The only problem is when I make a selection it appears that the ng-click function is not getting triggered, and I'm not sure why not. It isn't that it can't find the function in the controller; when I click on the menu item the behavior I see is as if the menu wasn't there at all and I just clicked on the label itself.

Here is the HTML where the directive is applied to a label:

```
<label toggle-clear="labelOne" context="labelOne">Label One</label>
```

When I run, if I inspect the element, I can see that the menu is there and that the ng-click call appears to be correct:

```
<label clearToggle="labelOne" context="labelOne">"Label One"
    <ul id="labelOne" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a ng-click="setClear(labelOne)">Set to Clear</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="unsetClear(labelOne)">Unset Clear</a></li>
    </ul>
</label>
```

This is the directive code:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('toggleClear', function ($parse, $compile) {
    return {
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            return function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var ulTemplate = "<ul id='"+attrs.context+"' class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>"+ 
                    "<li><a ng-click='setClear("+attrs.context+")'>Set to Clear</a></li>"+
                    "<li><a ng-click='unsetClear("+attrs.context+")'>Unset Clear</a></li>"+
                    "</ul>"
                $compile(ulTemplate)(scope);
                element.append(ulTemplate);
                var fn = $parse(attrs.ngRightClick);
                element.bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    fn(scope, {$event:event});
                });
            }
        }
    };
});

(function(angular) {
  var contextMenu = angular.module('directive.toggleClear', []);
  contextMenu.directive('cellHighlight', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function postLink(scope, el, attr) {
          el.find('td').mouseover(function() {
            $(this).parent('tr').css('opacity', '0.7');
          }).mouseout(function() {
            $(this).parent('tr').css('opacity', '1.0');
          });
        }
      };
  });

  contextMenu.directive('context', [
      function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: '@&',
          compile: function compile(contextElement, contextAttrs, transclude) {
            return {
              post: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
                var ul = $('#' + attrs.context),
                end = null;
                ul.css({
                    'display': 'none'
                });
                $(elem).bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    ul.css({
                      position: 'fixed',
                      display: 'block',
                      left: event.clientX + 'px',
                      top: event.clientY + 'px'
                    });
                    end = event.timeStamp;
                });
            $(document).click(function(event) {
              var target = $(event.target);
              if (!target.is(".popover") && !target.parents().is(".popover")) {
                if (end === event.timeStamp)
                  return;
                ul.css({
                  'display': 'none'
                });
              }
            });
            }
          };
        }
      };
    }
  ])
})(window.angular);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case some other soul comes across this while looking for a similar answer, after much tinkering I realized where I'd gone wrong. I was compiling the ulTemplate by itself and then append that to the element, when what I really needed to do was to append the ulTemplate to the element, and then compile the element.contents(). Also, I was missing quotes around the parameter being passed in the ng-click function. When all was said and done I ended up with this:

```
        var ulTemplate = "<ul id='"+attrs.context+"' class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>"+ 
                            "<li><a ng-click='setClear(\""+attrs.context+"\")'>Set to Clear</a></li>"+
                            "<li><a ng-click='unsetClear(\""+attrs.context+"\")'>Unset Clear</a></li>"+
                          "</ul>"
            element.append(ulTemplate);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
```